# What is the printf format for fixed string?

Tags: c, printf

Is this safe or UB ?

```
char x[5] = { 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e' };
printf("%5.5s\n", x);
```

What is the correct printf format to print a non-zero-terminated string ? (Or what is the format to print the first N characters of a c-string ?)

Comment: Your code works. The first `5` is not needed. `printf("%.*s\n", len, data);` where `len` has type `int`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The behavior is well defined. The argument corresponding to a plain `%s` conversion specifier must be a pointer to a *string* (which means, by definition, that it includes a null `'\0'` terminator), but if a precision is specified the argument doesn't have to be a pointer to a string (i.e., no null terminator as long as the array is long enough).

Quoting the C11 standard draft, [N1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) 7.21.6.1p8:

> Characters from the array are written up to (but not including) the
>   terminating null character. If the precision is specified, no more
>   than that many bytes are written. If the precision is not specified or
>   is greater than the size of the array, the array shall contain a null
>   character.

If you want to print the first N characters of a character array, where N isn't a constant, you can use a `*` to specify that the length is given as a separate argument. For example, given a character array of known length that doesn't contain a null character, you can do this:

```
const char s[5] = "hello"; /* no terminating null character */
printf("%.*s\n", (int)sizeof s, s);
```

Note that `sizeof` works here only because `s` is an array; if it were a pointer, `sizeof` would give you the size of a pointer, not the size of the array. Note also that the `*` requires an argument of type `int`; since `printf` is a variadic function, and `sizeof` yields a value of type `size_t`, you need the cast in this case.

Answer (score 2):

```
printf("%.5s", str);
```

The string does not have to be NUL terminated.

```
printf("%.*s", 5, str);
```

will also work.

Answer (score 1):

There is no C string that is not null terminated. For the solution if this you can try

```
printf("%.*s", len, str);
```

Where `len` is the number of characters you want to print and `str` is the string you are working on.

Additionally :

If width or precision are specified as an asterisk '*', an int from the argument list is used as the width or precision. If the width is too small the field is expanded.                                   Example:

```
    int len = 5;
    char *string = "This is a string"

    printf("%*.*s", len, len, "string");
```

is functionally similar to a specification string of "%5.5s"
      which prints a max of 5 characters of the string.

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question. The OP asked whether a call with `%5.5s` has defined behavior. Making the length a separate parameter doesn't make any difference (except that it's more flexible).

Comment: Sorry, I didn't read the question carefully enough. The OP asks two different things, whether `%5.5s` is safe or UB (which you didn't answer), and how to print the first N characters of a string (which you did, assuming N is not constant).

Comment: @Keith Sorry I do not have sufficient information about it thus I answered only that part which I was sure about. Thanks